# How to resolve issue with Hibernate plugin after upgrading from grails 2.0.4 to 2.3.6

Tags: hibernate, grails-2.0, grails-plugin, grails-2.3

I have upgraded my grails app from 2.0.4 to 2.3.6, I have hibernate dependency as follows

```
plugins{
   compile ":hibernate:2.2.5"
}
```

When running, it gives me error like this

```
C:\Users\vinay.hs\.grails\2.3.6\projects\opal\plugins\hibernate-2.2.5\.\Hibernat
eGrailsPlugin.groovy: 18: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plu
gins.orm.hibernate.HibernatePluginSupport
 @ line 18, column 1.
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.hibernate.HibernatePluginSupport
```

How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 2.3.6 you need `runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.8"`. Your best bet when upgrading is to create a new empty app and copy your code and changes there. At least create a throwaway app to see what's changed.

Comment: It looks like the JFrog versions of these packages only include the java source directory and not the groovy directory where HibernatePluginSupport lives.  I am looking at packages in the 3.6.10 range (especially 3.6.10.18 for upgrade to grails 2.4.5).  It looks like this also impacts the other version recommended - hibernate4:4.3.8.1.